Remove module from Gradle plugin
I have
id 'org.jetbrains.dokka' version '1.9.20'

and
dokkaPlugin("io.getstream:dokkasaurus:0.1.10")

When I'm trying to execute "./gradlew dokkaGfm" I get an error:
 Conflicting overrides: [Extension: org.jetbrains.dokka.gfm.GfmPlugin/renderer, Extension: io.getstream.dokkasaurus.DokkasaurusPlugin/renderer]

How to force use "DokkasaurusPlugin" renderer and solve conflict? Please help!
